# Apache not Proxying HTTPS requests to TomCat, Just showing local index.html

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, proxy, centos

Centos 7, Apache 2.4, TomCat 7.0.52, Java 1.7

I am trying to configure Apache to proxy a tomcat server (running Jira / Confluence) using HTTPS:

(HTTPS:443) -> ApacheServer -> (HTTP:8090 or HTTPS:8091) TomCat

Currently HTTP proxying works perfectly but I want to get HTTPS working. I dont mind if the connection between Apache and Tomcat is SSL (on the same server).

When I visit https://confluence.company.co.uk/ I get /var/www/html/index.html rather than the proxy.

Here is the Server.xml from tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
           maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="10"
           enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" debug="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

<Connector port="8091" proxyPort="443" proxyName="confluence.company.co.uk"   acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           redirectPort="8443" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" scheme="https" secure="true" />
```

Lines changed from default /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf from Apache:

```
ServerName confluence.company.co.uk:443
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/company.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/company.key
```

Apache VHost Configuration ( in /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_vhost.conf ):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  confluence.company.co.uk
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Proxy Auth"
            AuthUserFile /var/www/company-auth/CONFLUENCE/.htpasswd
            Require user ukuser
            Satisfy any
            Deny from all
            Allow from 192.168.0.0/21
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://confluence.company.co.uk:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://confluence.company.co.uk:8090/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://confluence.company.co.uk:8091/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://confluence.company.co.uk:8091/
</VirtualHost>
```

### Update

httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/4bzwKLac
ssl.conf: http://pastebin.com/M5FpJTMz

When I include ServerName in the HTTPS vhost, httpd doesn't start and I get the following error:

```
systemctl status httpd
   httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-07-22 13:00:22 BST; 7s ago
   Process: 25953 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Process: 15243 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 25951 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 25951 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Jul 22 13:00:21 confluence.syzygy.co.uk systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   Jul 22 13:00:22 confluence.syzygy.co.uk kill[25953]: kill: cannot find process ""
   Jul 22 13:00:22 confluence.syzygy.co.uk systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
   Jul 22 13:00:22 confluence.syzygy.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
   Jul 22 13:00:22 confluence.syzygy.co.uk systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

There does not seem to be anything related in the logs other than:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 25447] AH01916: Init: (confluence.company.co.uk:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
```

Which occurs seperately from HTTPd not starting

### Update 2

So I solved this by moving the following into the vhost in ssl.conf:

```
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://confluence.company.co.uk:8091/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://confluence.company.co.uk:8091/
```

Why can I net have it in my seperate vhost?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `ServerName confluence.company.co.uk` to your 433 vhost. This may cause httpd to default to a different TLS vhost.

Comment: What does httpd tell you when it doesn't want to start? I have trouble believing it would refuse a servername directive. Check your error log and let us know what it says :)

Comment: What does the httpd error log itself say? https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout will tell you where the log can be found.

Comment: I will have to see the entire httpd config to solve this. You are either configuring port 443 twice or you have an error in a ServerName directive somewhere.

Comment: I have included links to ssl.conf and httpd.conf on pastebin

Comment: You have `ServerName confluence.company.co.uk:443` in your configuration. Please remove the ':443' part of it and try again.